# Adding JAR files to the CodeRunner path for Java

Tags: java, jar, path

How can I add a JAR file to the PATH variable in CodeRunner on macOS Sierra?

I tried going into preferences>advanced and then changing the PATH variable. Then I restarted CodeRunner and ran a java file that referenced the JAR file. However the file still gave me an error that it could not find such files. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the way to do this!

You can edit the Run Settings (the wrench icon in the toolbar) for the program. Under Compile Flags type:

`-cp "<your jar file here>"`

That's what worked for me.